# Live audio stream using tcp indy10

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, audio-streaming

From their example http://www.delphiarea.com/products/delphi-packages/waveaudio/ (TLiveAudioRecorder)

```
//sender
    procedure TMainForm.LiveAudioRecorderData(Sender: TObject;
      const Buffer: Pointer; BufferSize: Cardinal; var FreeIt: Boolean);
    var
      I: Integer;
    begin
      FreeIt := True;
      for I := tcpServer.Socket.ActiveConnections - 1 downto 0 do
        with tcpServer.Socket.Connections[I] do
          if Data = Self then // the client is ready
            SendBuf(Buffer^, BufferSize);

    end;
```

How can I send the audio stream using TCP indy10 ?
something like `Connection.IOHandler.Write(Buffer, 0, true);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either:

1. Use `RawToBytes()` to copy the buffer data to a `TIdBytes` and then pass that to `TIdIOHandler.Write(TIdBytes)`:

   ```
   Connection.IOHandler.Write(RawToBytes(Buffer^, BufferSize));
   ```
2. Use `TIdMemoryBufferStream` to wrap the buffer in a `TStream` and pass that to `TIdIOHandler.Write(TStream)`:

   ```
   Strm := TIdMemoryBufferStream.Create(Buffer, BufferSize);
   Connection.IOHandler.Write(Strm);
   Strm.Free;
   ```